# Should a non-significant adjustment variable be kept in a regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, adjustment

I'm working with a structural equation model to study influenza infection risk. As age is a known risk factor to explain infection, I therefore adjusted my infection outcome on the subjects age class. After regressing my outcome on several latent variables, the age class is not significant anymore. My question is : should a non-significant adjustment variable be kept in a (structural) regression model or removed ?

Answer (score 0):

Beyond considering the SEM discussion in comment from @NickCox, I'd test different codings of your age variable before ruling out its inclusion.  I'm assuming you've transformed to categorical since the age relationship will be non-linear (very young and old people are more likely to be infected, everyone in between less so).  If you have enough data perhaps you could test as a continuous covariate with a quadratic age variable model; otherwise explore how you bin the ages into different sub groups to make sure that's not confounding the variable's influence.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this would shed light about inclusion since it should be included anyway.  But it is good to model continuous variables continuously and flexibly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to implicitly comment on whether it should or shouldn't be included. Just that the OP first consider whether the age variable's representation in the model (or any potential re-coding) might have been causing the significance issues.